# Do i need a separate Distribution for each Apple AppStore submission?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, appstore-approval

I'm so confused -

after an entire day's struggle, i finally figured out how to submit my app to Apple via archiving & distributing from xcode.

... that was my free version

now i made my code changes, and on my pList file, i changed the Bundle Identifier to `com.blah.mygame.pro` instead of `com.blah.mygame.lite`

i also changed the Bundle name to be `My Game Pro` instead of `My Game Lite`

but now i'm confused - when i click on the project in Xcode, and i hit "Target" instead of "Project", i can't find my release/distribution profile! (my develop/debug profile) is still there.

if i were to click `Project` instead of `Targets` then i actually do see my previous distribution profile.

however, in my develloper portal, i had actually set my distribution profile to be linked up with the "com.blah.mygame.lite" identifier. was i not supposed to do this???

weirdly enough, when i made my distrubution profile earlier today, i say something like "mygame * -" or something that i coulda linked it to. but i just chose `com.blah.mygame.lite` without thinking

are you supposed to have multiple distribution profiles? one for every app? what i just want a lite and pro version?

**** edit:

bonus points for this:

if i only needed 1 provisioning profile, (and since i messed up naming my previous provisioning profiles)... how do i rename all my distribution profiles without it interfering/messing up with my apps?? it's already submitted and awaiting approval

*** EDIT # 2:

okay, i got both apps submitted with 2 separate distribution profiles.

however, is there any way that i can rename a distribution profiles while the app being submitted is still using it??

i had mistakenly named it "My Company Distribution Profile" when i should have named it "Distribution Profile for My Game Pro Version"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options for fixing it:

- Use a `AppId` like. `com.blah.mygame.*` . You can replace the * with any number of strings and use it for creating different application.

  **I won't recommend this approach, because  the issue with this is you won’t be able to use push services or in-app purchases. You might not plan to use these services now, but if you change your mind, you won’t be able to change your app ID without creating a new app.**
- Create different `AppId` for different Apps. It'll be a good approach

Comment: i was thinking the same thing. but now that i've mis-named my distribution profiles, can i just rename them in the developer portal without anything going weird? or is that going to affect the submission process?

Comment: If you didn't submitted your app to appstore using that appid you can change that, else you need to upload a new app

Comment: once it gets approved, is it fine to change the provisioning profile after an app is already approved?

Comment: @DavidT.No, you can't do that, If app is approved. If you changed the profle and uploaded it with new binary. It'll taken as new app, not as an update to existing app. So never do it.

Comment: Which approach would you not recommend?  The former or the latter?  Your meaning is ambiguous.

Comment: @AdrianBartholomew Please read carefully. I'm talking about first approach. When you use wildcard app id you can't use push, it is easily understandable from the context itself. For the later one, I've already mentioned it's the good method.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're using a single AppID for both of your apps. You can only use one provisioning profile for multiple apps only if the AppID bound to that profile has a wildcard (e.g. "com.sample.*").

quoted from the [iOS Provisioning Portal](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/bundles/index.action):

> The Bundle Identifier portion of an App ID can be substituted with a
>   wild-card character (asterisk '*') so that a single App ID may be used
>   to build and install multiple applications. **If the wild-card character
>   is not used, the Bundle Identifier portion of your App ID must be
>   input as your CF Bundle ID in Xcode** to allow the application to
>   install on your device. The Bundle Seed ID portion of your App ID does
>   not need to be input into Xcode. Wild-card App IDs cannot be used with
>   the Push Notifications or for In-App Purchase.

Comment: i see it now. i made another distribution profile. however, is there a way i can somehow rename my old distribution profile something else? i named it "Company distribution profile" when i shoulda named it "Distribution profile for Pro version"

Comment: Just replace your old distribution profile. It won't affect your apps already released in the AppStore as long as they still use the same Bundle IDs. Reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG6

Comment: erh... isn't that for replacing certificate? my certificate is fine, i just needed to change the distribution provisioning profile. just a couple of minutes ago, i went back, renamed my provisioning profiles, redownloaded them, and took my apps off the queue for approval, and then re-archived and submitted. it was a bit of work, but this is prolly better for the long run

Comment: Good for you, I'd do the same since that feels cleaner. But Apple will code-sign your app with their own certificates, so it doesn't matter what certificate/provisioning combination you use, as long as it still is the same AppID (which you can't delete anyway)

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have created an `AppId` with this `bundle identifier` **com.blah.mygame.lite** and created a distribution profile linked with this `AppId`. By doing like that, you can run or archive your apps only if it is having the `same AppId` like this `com.blah.mygame.lite`. If you want to create an `AppId` to run all apps, then you need a `Wildcard AppId` like this `com.*` . And If you think you need to run the app with `AppId com.blah.mygame.pro` then you need to create another `appId` like that and associate that `appId` with **another distribution profile or modify the old one** and download and install it and use.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of distribution profile for every app....one is enough for every time but

your bundle identifier is same as you given in your distribution provisioning profile when

you create it first time....

Comment: But if you getting any problem then you can revoke your previous one & make new one for new app while submission...