# How to safely rename iOS Distribution Profile?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, app-store, provisioning-profile

I just submitted my first app a couple of hours ago and is now in the status "waiting for review"

but i had made one mistake -

i had named my *distribution* provisioning profile `My Company Distribution Profile`. what i SHOULD have done instead was named my distribution provisioning profile `My GAME Distribution Profile`.

now that the app is pending approval, and i plan to make future updates to my apps, is there a way i can safely rename my distribution provisioning profile?

as in... i'm worried that by re-naming my current distribution profile.... would i never be able to make updates to the currently submitted app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are adamant about changing the provisioning name while your app is pending, you can go ahead and reject your binary. Then do your changes in the provisioning name and also incorporate it in the app that you are going to submit and re-submit your binary again. You might lose the place you have in the line for waiting to be reviewed but it really does not make much of a difference. So I suggest you reject the binary and do your changes then re-submit.

Comment: i'm going to be uploading more apps later, and also, it'll be really confusing for future comers to the team to be seeing "oh look! `company distribution profile`, i should use that one!"

Comment: a proper name for your team provisioning is a good practice for future. also try using separate wild cards for each app so when you get to upload so many apps it would be easier for your future team members to be allocated to each app separately. it is just a good organizational point. i work with 19 different teams and also have my own work so it can become confusing if the names are generic.

Answer (score 2):

**If you change the provisioning profile and uploads your app with this changed provisioning it'll be taken as new app, not as the update of existing app, because of the difference in provisioning.**

What is the issue with the misnamed profile ? No one can see that other than you. So don't worry about that.

Comment: i plan to upload a lot of apps later on, and having one or two provision profiles in your portal named "company distribution profile" is rather misleading for me & ppl who come in later :( thanks for ur answers though

Comment: I agree with this answer (I am not against @Amp's answer, It is correct way, too), as "company distribution profile" will be seen just once or say twice to the developer next to you, If that's your concern. No one is going to see Profile name each and every day before He/She Develops further.

Comment: Hmm.. what do you mean by "seen just once or twice to the developer next to you" ? i thought anyone who can log in to the developer portal will see it? But relax, I've upvoted his answer & the other one, and accepted another one of his answer to my similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765146/do-i-need-a-separate-distribution-for-each-apple-appstore-submission/ :)