# Rename xcode generated provisioning profile

Tags: xcode, xcode4, provisioning, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

XCode creates and manages a provisioning profile for wildcard apps.
I would like to change the profile name so it's not so easily mixed with other wildcard profiles from other teams.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766643/how-to-safely-rename-ios-distribution-profile

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate. I'm asking about how to change the xcode autogenerated "iOS Team provisiong profile" not the other profiles which i create myself

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible in the current version of the 'Certificates, Identities, and Profiles' tool on developer.apple.com.

Because this profile was created by Xcode, the operations available to us via this tool are quite limited:

[image: Team Provisioning Profile]

For those Profiles we've manually created we can select the 'Edit' button and provide a new name for the profile (so long as you don't include any special characters!), however in the case of these special Xcode-generated Provisioning Profiles and App IDs (as indicated by the parenthetical 'Managed by Xcode' in the upper right of the attached screenshot) the only available operation is 'Delete'.

What isn't clear is if this is only a temporary issue while Apple finishes working out the kinks in this new version of the Provisioning Center, if it is a more permanent behavior we are going to have to live with, or even if future versions of Xcode will continue to auto-generate Wildcard AppIDs and Team Provisioning Profiles.  **Regardless, there is nothing you can do to rename/reorganize these profiles at the current time.**

*Warning: Pure Speculation Follows:* Given that the documentation is littered with references to the Team Provisioning Profile capabilities of Xcode and the the 'Certificates, Identifiers, and Profiles' tool, I'd hazard a guess that in a future version of Xcode we will have the ability to refresh these profiles.  There are **a ton** of people experiencing problems ranging from Xcode hanging all the way up to a complete Xcode crash as a result of these profiles, so Apple will almost certainly be doing something.  Hopefully when they do so, some of these relatively minor annoyances in the Portal will also go away.